# Listing all available shared drives in a google drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to list all google shared drives using below api

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?pageSize=100&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

But can i list all drives with out giving pagesize parameter? It also says page limit is 100. Is there anyway we can list all drives without any limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation for [drives.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/list) you will see that it states

> pageSize   integer Maximum number of shared drives to return. Acceptable values are 1 to 100, inclusive. (Default: 10)

There is no way to set the page size parameter over 100.  No you cant get drives without any limits the limits are in place so that we can all use the API together without any one person making a huge call that takes a lot of processing power.

you will need to use the page token and paginate your request.

Comment: Any other way i can pass the drive name in parameter and list only the specific drive details. for eg. Drive name = Sales

Comment: check out the q parameter on the drives list call  Link [search shared drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-shareddrives) but you need special permissions to use this i think.